# Парсинг столбцов текстового файла

Tags: c#

Каким способом можно спарсить столбцы и добавить их в класс. А затем к ним обратиться по мере надобности

```
public class Detail
{
    public string Ch { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Duplex { get; set; }
    public string Speed { get; set; }
    public string Neg { get; set; }
    ...   
}
```

Пример данных, которые нужно спарсить:

```
Ch       Type    Duplex  Speed  Neg      control  State         Port Mode (VLAN)        
-------- ------- ------  -----  -------- -------  ------------- ------------------------
Po1         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present   Access (1)              
Po2         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present   Access (1)              
Po3         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present   Access (1)              
Po4         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present   Access (1)
```

---

### Дополнение

Видел в интернет что то подобное, но это не работает. Не знаю как обратиться к неинициализированному объекту

```
Parse(log, ' ');

public IEnumerable<Detail> Parse(string source, char delimiter)
{
    return source.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1)
        .Select(x =>
        {
            var detail = x.Split(new[] { delimiter });
            return new Detail
            {
                Ch = detail[0],
                Type = detail[1],
                Duplex = detail[2],
                Speed = detail[3],
                Neg = detail[4]
            };
        });
}
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример данных в виде текста, а не в виде картинки.

Comment: `x.Split(new[] { "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` - сплитаем по двум пробелам, чтобы `Not Present` обработалось как одно целое. И удаляем пустые подстроки.

Comment: Похоже, файл у вас хорошо форматирован: все колонки строго заданной длины. Вот можно по длине и брать подстроки с помощью `Substring` (или лучше `Span<char>.Splice`, если у вас C# 8)

Comment: @motpfofs поправил

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  если не сложно, то не могли бы вы привести пример

Comment: Я вижу вывод на консоль с циски в файл. может вам следует для начала описать зачем вы это делаете, а уже потом спрашивать как это сделать с файлом? Возможно стоит брать эти данные для анализа не из файла, а напрямую с коммутатора по SNMP?

Comment: @Yakov файл для примера. Вся работа идет с telnet

Comment: ИМХО, телнет штука не секурная, если вводится пароль для входа, то его можно легко перехватить, если этот траффик не идет в отдельном влане. вы задачу то озвучте зачем вы эти данные хотите парсить, может вам подскажут готовый софт которого море, и не нужно будет велосипед изобретать с телнетами )))

Comment: Так же советую использовать SNMP, он как бы специально предназначен для считывания данных с аппаратуры.

Answer (score 1):

Немного монструозно получилось, но решал без регулярок и в лоб. На гениальность не претендую.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = @"Ch       Type    Duplex  Speed  Neg      control  State         Port Mode (VLAN)        
-------- ------- ------  -----  -------- -------  ------------- ------------------------
Po1         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present   Access (1)              
Po2         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present   Access (1)              
Po3         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present   Access (1)              
Po4         --     --      --      --       --    Not Present   Access (1)    ";

        foreach (Detail d in ParseLog(text))
            Console.WriteLine(d);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Detail> ParseLog(string source)
    {
        string[] lines = source.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n").Split('\n');

        List<(int, int)> columnsIndex = new List<(int, int)>();
        int start = 0;
        bool isHeader = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines[1].Length; i++)
        {
            if (!isHeader && lines[1][i] == '-')
            {
                start = i;
                isHeader = true;
            }
            else if (isHeader && (lines[1][i] == ' ' || i == lines[1].Length - 1))
            {
                columnsIndex.Add((start, i - start));
                isHeader = false;
            }
        }

        foreach (string line in lines.Skip(2))
        {
            List<string> values = new List<string>();
            foreach ((int offset, int length) in columnsIndex)
            {
                values.Add(line.Substring(offset, offset + length > line.Length ? line.Length - offset : length).Trim());
            }
            if (values.Count > 7)
                yield return new Detail
                {
                    Ch = values[0],
                    Type = values[1],
                    Duplex = values[2],
                    Speed = values[3],
                    Neg = values[4],
                    Control = values[5],
                    State = values[6],
                    PortMode = values[7],
                };
        }
    }
}

public class Detail
{
    public string Ch { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Duplex { get; set; }
    public string Speed { get; set; }
    public string Neg { get; set; }
    public string Control { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PortMode { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
        => string.Join(", ", GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetValue(this)));
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Po1, --, --, --, --, --, Not Present, Access (1)
Po2, --, --, --, --, --, Not Present, Access (1)
Po3, --, --, --, --, --, Not Present, Access (1)
Po4, --, --, --, --, --, Not Present, Access (1)
```

Comment: Разве практичнее нельзя было сделать ?

Comment: @Tand не понял вопроса, звучит как плохой отзыв о коде, что именно здесь не практично?

Comment: Много не нужного кода как по мне, я думаю есть вариант это сократить в 2 раза

Comment: @Tand ваше право.

Answer (score -1):

Я немного поправил код, который вы предложили. Это однозначно не самое оптимальное решение и я уверен, что предложат лучше, но всё же:

1. С помощью регулярных выражений заменяем все пробелы (которые идут подряд больше двух) на определённый нами сепаратор
2. Разбиваем строку используя наш сепаратор

```
public static IEnumerable<Detail> ParseLog(string source)
{
    return source.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(2)
        .Select(x =>
        {
            RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
            Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);
            x = regex.Replace(x, "#sep#");

            var detail = x.Split("#sep#");
            return new Detail
            {
                Ch = detail[0].Trim(),
                Type = detail[1].Trim(),
                Duplex = detail[2].Trim(),
                Speed = detail[3].Trim(),
                Neg = detail[4].Trim()
            };
        });
}
```

Comment: У вас ошибка. Split работает только с типом данных char !

Comment: Да и этот пример у меня все равно не работает, я же писал об этом.

Comment: @Tand Уверены [про Split](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CCnf6G)?)

Comment: @Tand вы передаете в аргумент весь текст или одну строку?

Comment: using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("data.txt"))
            {
              log= sr.ReadToEnd();  
            }
           
            ParseLog(log);

Comment: Ещё лучше использовать `Regex.Split`. Тогда не нужен `Replace`.

Comment: @Tand - в программировании нет такого понятия "не работает". Есть конкретная ошибка с полным описанием и указанием точного места.

Comment: @Tand - обратите внимание: у вас в коде `Skip(1)`, а надо как здесь: `Skip(2)` - пропускаем две первые строки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ошибок не возникает, проблема в том что этот код попросту игнорируется source.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(2)

Comment: @Tand к сожалению я сейчас не у компьютера, но я проверил код (скомпилировав его) перед тем, как отвечать на вопрос. Если передавать этому методу строку указанную в вопросе как пример данных, то он возвращает распарсеные объекты.

Comment: @motpfofs  как мне взять данные класса Detail.Ch . Detail Detail = new Detail(); так будет пусто

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял то так: ‘var details = ParseLog(log); foreach(var detail in details){ Console.WriteLine(detail.Ch); }’

Comment: @motpfofs у меня возникает ошибка в коде в строчке. То что Split не может работать со string.  var detail = x.Split("#sep#");

Comment: @motpfofs если заменить  это x.Split("#sep#") на x.Split('&') то все работает отлично

Comment: Рад, что вы нашли решение. 

Comment: @motpfofs интересно было бы пропустить только вторую строчку, а не две сразу